# What do these Heap Summary categories mean in Windows Phone Application Analysis?

Tags: visual-studio, profiling, heap-memory, analysis, summary

I can't figure out what these Heap Summary mean when perform Windows Phone Application Analysis in Visual Studio 2012.

They are

1. Retained Allocations at Start
2. New Allocations
3. Collected Allocations
4. Retained Allocations at End
5. Retained Visuals at Start
6. Retained Visuals at End

Any explanation or documents are appreciated